# Ruby 2.x method keyword arguments. Match current scope's variable names

Tags: ruby, arguments

When using Ruby 2.x keyword arguments style for methods I'd like to make the method call shorter ( by matching scoped params name with current scope variable names):

```
def count_now(one:,two:,three:)
  puts "#{one}...#{two}...#{three}"
end

one='Un'
two='Dos'
three='Tres'

count_now(one:,two:,three:) #<-- How can I tell it to search for those vars in the current scope?

=>"Un...Dos...Tres"
```

I'm sure there's a way!

Comment: [There is an way](https://gist.github.com/cremno/1b86d1a6e22c0b7a6e8a) but it isn't short. Or were you looking for an abomination like this? Oh, and in your specific example there's an simpler way but you wouldn't be able to define other lvars (like `four`).

Comment: omg no! Thanks for the example anyway. I was looking for something more compact à la ruby, for example: `count_down(one:&,two:&,three:&)`. Some kind of special character.